# How to write isolated unit tests for routes in Play 2.0 framework?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework-2.0

My play framework application is in scala (not Java).  I found a page describing how to use the utility class play.test.Helpers for unit testing routes.  The example was in Java, not scala.  I wrote the test in scala, but I get the error "Message: This is not a JavaAction and can't be invoked this way."

Here is the page I found describing how to unit test routes in play framework 2.0:  http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/05/28/play-framework-2-tutorial-testing/

...and here is the code I tried to write to test my app:

```
package conf
import org.scalatest._
import play.mvc.Result
import play.test.Helpers._

class routeTest extends FunSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  describe("route tests") {
    it("") {
      // routeAndCall() fails.  Message: This is not a JavaAction and can't be invoked this way.
      val result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/"))
      result should not be (null)
    }
  }
}
```

Is the problem because my action is Scala and not Java?  Can I unit test my routes over Scala controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `play.api.*` imports from Scala code. `play.*` is a Java api. So your code should look like:

```
package conf

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

class routeTest extends FunSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  describe("route tests") {
    it("GET / should return result") {
      val result = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))
      result should be ('defined)
    }
  }
}
```

Or even better using `FlatSpec`:

```
package conf

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

class routeTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  "GET /" should "return result" in {
    val result = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))
    result should be ('defined)
  }

  it should "return OK" in {
    val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))
    status(result) should be (OK)
  }

}
```

Also, `routeAndCall` doesn't return null. It returns `Option[Result]`, i.e. `Some[Result]` or `None`, so null check doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Thank you!  I wondered the difference between play.api.* and play.*, but never had a problem before.  Much gratitude.  A small change:  I found "fakeRequest(GET. "/)"  needed to be "FakeRequest(GET. "/)", but everything else was perfect.  Thanks again.